# python lru_cache invalidate at a specific time (1PM)

Tags: python, flask, caching, lru

I am currently working on a problem where in I have a background scheduler that updates the a local file. In the main app (flask), I read have a function to load the file with a Lru_cache for 24 hours. How can

```
@lru_cache
def load_file(ttl_hash):
    load the file
```

Instead of passing the time to invalidate the cache , I want to remove the cache at a specified time . Is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need `load_file.cache_clear()` to clear the cache, and something to run the code at the specified time, for which [schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) seems to work well.